# joomla extension UPS - virtual mart - set delivary method

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

We have purchased the extension http://extensions.virtuemart.net/extensions-virtuemart-2/ups-detail to put in our website.

We have configured the module and our UPS account. The issue we are facing is regarding the Delivery method. We want to show “UPS Ground, UPS 3 Day Select, UPS 2 Day Air, UPS Next Day” in the shipping.

In joomla configuration page, when we search for these options in delivery method, those are not coming but others are coming like "Worldwide Express, Worldwide Express Plus, Worldwide Expedited" which are for international delivery.

What we are missing so that we can get options like "2nd Day Air AM, 2nd Day Air, 3 Day Select" in the configuration panel. We searched everything but not able to find it. Can you please help me?

Michal

Comment: You should contact the extension developers for this. It's not a question for SO

Comment: i have, but they have not responded. Can you tell me what i need to verify in case anything i am missing?

Comment: Did you set the vendor info correctly zip,state etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jobin.

We have updated "Additional Information" tab from "shop" options and set the vendor information as per USA.

Thanks